# SQL Conundrum - select single entry from Many-To-Many join

Tags: sql, sas, many-to-many

```
Activity  Activity  Sector 
code A    code B    code B
452543    600       BOU
452543    601       BOU
452543    602       BOU
51411     688       GTH
51411     689       GTH
51425     702       GTH
51425     703       GTH
51487     748       GTH
```

I have two tables I need to join. Table 1 holds 200 variables with among others "Activity Code A".  Table 2 is partially represented above.
Note that in Table 2, neither "Activity Code A" nor "Sector Code B" is unique.

Given an "Activity Code A" in Table 1, I need to get one single "Sector Code B".

Does anybode know how to construct the appropriate SQL?

Comment: Can you add table2 separately and expected output?. it will be much better to understand

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what your output requirement is. If you only need the `Sector Code B` you can use `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Sector Code B"
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE t2."Activity Code A" = Table1ActivityCodeAVar;
```

This will work so long as the values of `Sector Code B` are always the same for all `Activity Code A` rows.